# Is there a way to get R instead of r squared in R regression?

Tags: r, regression

I would like to have the correlation coefficient `R` instead of coefficient of determination `r2`.
I wonder if there is a way to get it from the regression analyses.

```
        t = c(1,2,5,4,8,7,5,1,2,5,4,1,2,1,5)
        t1 = c(1,2,4,4,5,3,7,5,6,8,7,1,2,1,5)
        y = c(1,2,1,4,4,6,5,8,5,7,3,1,4,1,5)
```

for `r.squared` simply do this

```
      summary(lm(y ~ t + t1))$r.squared
```

But for `R`? any idea

Comment: Why not simply take `sqrt(summary(lm(y ~ t + t1))$r.squared)`?

Comment: Even so - that would be the correct result if you are interested in `r`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also calculate the correlation of the response variable `y` against the predicted values by using the function `cor`:

```
cor(predict(lm(y ~ t + t1)), y)
```

Comment: This is simply treated as a vector, which is subsequently compared to the vector `y`.